# Undefined symbol TLSv1 with python+perforce

Tags: python, perforce

I installed the p4 library on my local archlinux machine and everything works smoothly.
I was now trying to do the same on a couple of virtual machines (with same OS also 64 bits) but can't get it running...

The installation goes well and doesn't complain, but when I try to import it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "P4.py", line 312, in <module>
    import P4API
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/P4API.so: undefined symbol: TLSv1_method
```

If I look in the symbols with
nm -A /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/P4API.so

I can see that in fact all the SSL-related symbols are undefined (while being defined on the working one), but why on earth?
I have openssl installed and Python is installed in exactly the same way, I can't find any other library that should be useful.

Any idea?

EDIT:
apparently the only difference is that in the wrong installation of P4 P4API.so is missing librt from the "ldd" output (and librt is actually there).
Not sure how it would relate to the TLS problem, and trying to reinstall glibc and then 
p4python but no luck still..

Comment: Hi Andrea, can you check which SSL libraries you are using locally and in your VMs? You can use the command `openssl version`.

Comment: "OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012", exactly the same on the host and the guest machines, but on the guests it just seems to not care..

Comment: Andrea, might there be a problem with static vs dynamic libraries? What does "ldd P4API.so" say on your real and VM machines?

Comment: Ok found the issue (but not the solution yet), the virtual machine is missing librt from the ldd, which is actually there though. Now I reinstalled glibc and trying again, let's see what happens..

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding the P4Python against the "rt" and "ssl" libraries fixes this.

1. Take the P4 API off the perforce site (e.g. for Linux take this: http://filehost.perforce.com/perforce/r13.2/bin.linux26x86_64/p4api.tgz)
2. Take the source code of P4Python off http://public.perforce.com/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/API/python/main/p4python.zip
3. `tar xf` the P4 API archive
4. Unzip the p4pthon archive
5. Edit `setup.cfg` to point to the P4API directory
6. Edit `setup.py` and go to line 120 and add "ssl" and "rt" so it looks like this

   ```
   else: # Assume Linux
       libraries = ["client", "rpc", "supp", "ssl", "rt"]    # P4API libs
       extra_compile_args = ["-DOS_LINUX", "-D%s" % p4_api_ver]
   ```
7. Do `sudo python setup.py install`